# printf not outing thing read from scanf

Tags: c

scanf can read optimally signed decimal,octal, or hexadecimal input but printf can't output said read input? Or is there some other specifier I'm not aware of and not using.

example code

```
scanf("%i", &x);     //enter 0150 (octal)                     
printf("%i ",x);     //outputs 104(decimal)
```

Comment: Read the man page for `printf`. It has a list of all of the conversion specifiers.

Comment: those specifiers are specific, but I was wondering if there was one specifier that encompassed 3 specifiers

Comment: %i can read optimally signed decimal,octal, or hexadecimal  and the argument is pointed to an int.

Comment: @vvid No, because C is not an object-oriented language, so variable `x` contains no information except a value. You need to choose the format that you want to use to display that value.

Comment: @chux, damn, I stand corrected. I had my `printf` and `scanf` swapped.

Comment: Let us pretend there was such a specifier, called `Z`.  What would you expect `printf("%Z ",x);` to print?  `x` has no "memory" of how its value originated.

Comment: @chux it could be made to work if `%z` consumed 2 arguments, one for the base and another for the value.  Kind of like `%*s` consumes 2 arguments.

Comment: @Tom Karzes You mean like [TO_BASE(x, 2), TO_BASE(x, 36)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34292061/2410359)?

Comment: @chux Yeah pretty much, but without the need to provide storage for the result.

Comment: @Tom Karzes Note, no storage variables were explicitly declared.  IAC, I was hoping to find OP's point-of-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there is no specifier that does what %i can do in scanf, I wasn't sure if there was one or not but ichan confirmed that there isn't one

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is another specifier. You should read as string and write what you read to write exactly what you read.

```
char x[100];
scanf("%99s", x);
printf("%s ", x);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but there might be some problem with the data type which not actually a numeric. Since it's in array of char, some might found it difficult to operate/manipulate the array of char with other numeric data. Still, it's nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

See here, `printf` doesn't identify "%i" and "%d" separately. But it is identified in `scanf`.
Also please write the question properly next time :)

These links may help you-

1. [Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)
2. [Octal to Decimal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895600/octal-to-decimal-in-c)
3. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Answer (score -1):

You might found this reference is useful to you:

**printf**
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
[image: printf]

**scanf**
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/
[image: scanf]

---

**EDIT:**
There is no single specifier, that one size fit all. You should know what you will be printing, and use the specific specifier to get the job done.

Comment: The input is not known and is determined by the user. But I see, if there is no one size fits all then I am out of luck

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11383535)

Comment: @Magisch I've been added the answer from the link. I'm using image, since Stack Overflow doesn't support <table> html tag.